# VB.NET Date/Time formatting issues with Linq to SQL

Tags: vb.net, linq, datetime-format

I'm pulling in datetime information from SQL, converting it to a string then using substring to chop it in date, hour, and minute variables. In the database, the date is shown as MM/dd/YYYY, and the month/day always use two digits (such as 09/04/2016) but after the query it shows up in my application as (9/4/2016) which throws off my substring count. How do I get my query to keep the 0 in front when necessary?

```
Private Sub pullDate()
        pulledDate = dgvTimeManager.SelectedItem.TimeIn.ToString
        pulledDate = pulledDate.Substring(0, 10)

        datepickerEdit.SelectedDate = Date.Parse(pulledDate)
End Sub

Private Sub pullStartTime()
        pulledStartTime = dgvTimeManager.SelectedItem.TimeIn.ToString

        If pulledStartTime.Length = 22 Then
            pulledStartHour = pulledStartTime.Substring(11, 2)
            pulledStartMinute = pulledStartTime.SubString(14, 2)
            pulledStartAMPM = pulledStartTime.SubString(20, 2)
        ElseIf pulledStartTime.Length = 21 Then
            pulledStartHour = pulledStartTime.SubString(11, 1)
            pulledStartMinute = pulledStartTime.SubString(13, 2)
            pulledStartAMPM = pulledStartTime.SubString(19, 2)
        End If

        If pulledStartAMPM = "AM" Then
            comboStartEditAMPM.SelectedIndex = 0
        ElseIf pulledStartAMPM = "PM" Then
            comboStartEditAMPM.SelectedIndex = 1
        End If

        txtStartHrEdit.Text = pulledStartHour
        txtStartMinEdit.Text = pulledStartMinute
End Sub
```

dgvtimemanger is the datagrid that's displaying my time table, the starttime.length conditions are to take into account the hour being displayed as one digit or two (the same thing i'm dealing with now for the date)

Comment: Could you update your question and provide the code you already have in place please.

Comment: If you retrieve the datetime as a `DateTime` type instead of a string you can simply access the `Date`, `Hour`, and `Minute` properties instead of substringing

Comment: Is it stored in SQL as DATETIME or String?

Comment: What is `dgvTimeManager` that it has a `SelectedItem`; then *that* has a `TimeIn` property???.  Looks like late binding.  There is no need to torture dates like that.  they have Day, Mon, Year properties/values

Comment: @Jinx88909 updated my question to show code

Comment: @Verdolino It's in SQL as a DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're spending **way** too much effort working with strings. Use the `DateTime` value you're given, and this code gets *much* simpler:

```
Private Sub pullDate()
    datepickerEdit.SelectedDate = dgvTimeManager.SelectedItem.TimeIn.Date
End Sub

Private Sub pullStartTime()
    Dim pulledStartTime As DateTime = dgvTimeManager.SelectedItem.TimeIn
    txtStartHrEdit.Text = pulledStartTime.ToString("hh")
    txtStartMinEdit.Text = pulledStartTime.ToString("mm")
    comboStartEditAMPM.SelectedIndex = If(pulledStartTime.Hour >= 12, 1, 0)         
End Sub
```

Additionally, I'd tend to write these kind of methods to accept an argument:

```
Private Sub SetStartTime(DateTime timeToSet)
    datepickerEdit.SelectedDate = timeToSet.Date
    txtStartHrEdit.Text = timeToSet.ToString("hh")
    txtStartMinEdit.Text = timeToSet.ToString("mm")      
    comboStartEditAMPM.SelectedIndex = If(timeToSet.Hour >= 12, 1, 0)   
End Sub
```

And then call them like this:

```
SetStartTime(dgvTimeManager.SelectedItem.TimeIn)
```

Note how the first one is so simple it's not even worth building the method anymore, and so I instead include the code as part of setting the time.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of converting to a string use the properties on the DateTime object. For example:

```
pulledStartHour = pulledStartTime.Hour.ToString("00")
```

will return the hour (in 24 hour format) which you then convert to a string.

You could also use .ToString(format) instead.

```
pulledStartHour = pulledStartTime.ToString("hh")
pulledStartAMPM = pulledStartTime.ToString("tt")
```

Which gives you the hours (in 12 hour format) and the AM/PM.

You can also combine the string foramts:

```
pulledStartTime.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx